# In a newgame+, what happens to promoted MP characters?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I've just recently started a NG+, but I haven't yet gotten to the point where I'm given free run of the Normandy and the Galaxy in general, so I can't see any kind of war assets.

I have several multiplayer characters reasonably close to 20; what'll happen if I promote them before I get access to the war room in single player?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your promoted characters are shared across all your single player games in the form of war assets.  Once you reach the point that you can use your war room, you'll be able to see them listed under N7.

This will also mean that its entirely possible to completely lock yourself out of seeing any ending other than the 'best' ending due to having too many war assets from promotion (but it would take a LOT).

Comment: Glad to hear it -- I'll play on to the war room tonight and check to make sure, then I'll accept.

Comment: Confirmed, both of my promoted vets were there.